# Is angularjs capable of filtering based on keywords?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have 30 categories in mysql.
I have 450 subcategories which are related to the 30 categories in another table.

Categories table
**id _ title _ Keywords**
1 _ Animals _ animal, animals, pet, parrot
2 _ Books _  books, book, educational
n _ xxx _ xxx

Subcategories table
**id _ ref _ title _ keywords**
1 _ 1 _ cats _ cats, persian cat, bengal cat
2 _ 1 _ dogs _ dogs, labrador, golder retriver
3 _ 2 _ Classic _ The davinci code, books, book, classical books

I need to implement the filter to a textfield. If the users enters labrador in the textfield then show the categories or/and subcategories which contain 'labrador' in the keywords.
In this case the "dogs" subcategory would appear!

I know that this has been done using jquery. But is there anyway to implement this with angularJs? 
If you got a jsfiddle then it would be awesome! :) 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sort of chose a different path.  This just modifies the model using some underscore filters.  It's kinda rough, but it could be a good place to start.

http://jsfiddle.net/bfricka/J3kDS/

Comment: BTW, I would pull the matching out into a separate method a la DRY, but you get the idea.

Comment: +1 for letting me see the question in a new light and for the nice looking results :)

Comment: Your solution is far more elegant, but thanks for the upvote. New user restrictions suck :)

Answer (score 2):

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NxZVt/1/) may help you get started. Try typing in 'labrador' in the textbox and notice the second drop down only shows dogs. If you type in 'persian' the second drop down only shows cats.

Most of the work is happening in the subcategory [select](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect) filter in `ng-options`:

```
<select ng-model="selectedSubCategory" ng-options="c.title for c in subcategories | filter:{ref: selectedCategory.id, keywords:keyword}"></select>
```

The [filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter) filter allows you to limit the bound array by multiple fields. In this example it is filtering by two things:

1. The `ref` on `subcategories` based on the `selectedCategory` in the first select drop down. This by itself displays only the subcategories matching the category currently selected.
2. The `keywords` on `subcategories` based on the `keyword` typed into the input textbox. This means as you type something into the textbox the value is being updated in the `$scope.keyword` model and automatically filtering `subcategories` for any `keywords` that contain the text typed in.

**Update:** after seeing bfricka's take I may have misunderstood your question. I [tweaked the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NxZVt/3/) and added `allCategories` to the model combining `categories` and `subcategories` and a filter only against the keyword typed in displaying the results in the `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-repeat="c in allCategories | filter:{keywords:keyword}">{{c}}</div>
```